# Specifying whether or not to lazily load with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a lazy fetch type collection in an entity. And I am using Spring Data (JpaRepository) for accessing the entities.

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
@Id
private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> children;
}
```

I want two functions in service class and current implementation are as following:

1. "children" should be null when fetching parent

   ```
   public Parent getParent(Long parentId){
       return repo.findOne(parentId);
   }
   ```
2. "children" should be filled when fetching parent:

   ```
    public Parent getParentWithChildren(Long parentId){
        Parent p = repo.findOne(parentId);
        Hibernate.initialize(p.children);
        return p;
   }
   ```

When returning "Parent" entity from a RestController, following exception is thrown:

```
@RequestMapping("/parent/{parentId}")
public Parent getParent(@PathVariable("parentId") Long id)
{
    Parent p= parentService.getParent(id);//ok till here
    return p;//error thrown when converting to JSON
}
```

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role: com.entity.Parent.children, could not initialize proxy - no
>   Session (through reference chain: com.entity.Parent["children"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role: com.entity.Parent.children, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain:
>   com.entity.Parent["children"])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking to allow for different JSON representations of the same domain model depending on use case, then you can look at the following which will allow you to do so without requiring DTOs:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Alternatively, see also the 'Projections in Spring Data REST' section in the following

https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra#projections-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: I think link #1 is perfect in our case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The RestController should return a `ParentDTO` instead of `Parent` entity. `ParentDTO` can be populated in a Transactional service method.

Comment: Our actual entity is far more complex and bigger than the sample code I wrote. ParentDTO would be too much of maintenance overhead for us.

Comment: With entities you might get circular dependency issues when converting them to json.

Comment: Hmm.. so I will either have to create DTO or remove children completely. Circular dependency was resolved with an annotation.

Comment: JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference were used to solve circular dependency issue

Comment: Does the caller of `/parent/{parentId}` need the entire complexity of the `Parent` entity (which is pretty big)? If no, then DTO should definitely be preferred.

Comment: Actually yes, each and every field is required. That's why initial thought was to have one which returned children and one which did not.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown because the JSON serializer requires all properties to be already initialized. So, all REST Controllers that need to return a Parent, have to initialize the properties first:

```
@RequestMapping("/parent/{parentId}")
public Parent getParent(@PathVariable("parentId") Long id) {
    return parentService.getParentWithChildren(id);
}
```

The `getParentWithChildren` Service method is run inside a transaction, and associated Hibernate Session is closed when the transaction is committed. This means you have to initialize all properties while the Hibernate Session is still open (inside the Service method).

You can also use the [Spring Data entity graph](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-466) support:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraphs(@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Parent.children", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("children")))
public class Parent{
@Id
private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> children;
}
```

And the `getParentWithChildren` method becomes:

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Parent.children", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Parent getParentWithChildren(Long parentId);
}
```

So, you don't even need to implement the:

1. getParent
2. getParentWithChildren

These methods can be supplied by Spring Data.

Comment: Hi, but I do not want to get children of parent in getParent() method. I want children to be null.

Comment: That's not how JPA works, you shouldn't set collections to null. You can fetch the Parant and transform it to a DTO which doesn't have the children.

Comment: Got it. Fetching collections is heavy burden and managing DTOs is also a heavy burden in our case. So we are probably going with Alan Hay's solution.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad you found the expected answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you did not show us the `Child` Java class: I hope the property is called `parentId` and not `parent`:

```
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parentId;
}
```

Solution 1: your code is actually correct, just that you MUST use a second layer of [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s (simple POJO classes) for transporting your domain layer to the client/browser. If you do not do so, after you will solve your Lazy Exceptions you will get a problem with the circular dependency from Parent to Child and the JSON marshaller (Jackson) will try to encode a `Child`, then its `Parent`, then again its children, then again their `Parent` and so on. An example of DTO would be:

```
public class ParentDto {
    private Long id;
    private String prop1;

    public ParentDto(Parent parent) {
            this.id = parent.id;
            this.prop1 = parent.prop1;
            //...other properties
    }

    //here come all getters for the properties defined above.
}
```

Solution 2: Use [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) for your public property `Parent.getChildren()`, so that the Jackson does not try to encode the children when marshalling the `Parent` instance.

Comment: I had used JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference to manage the problem of circular dependency. Is DTO the only option? Our actual entity is quite huge and complex, maintaining DTO causes huge overhead. Is there no other solution?

Comment: I have added another solution (with @JsonIgnore).

Comment: Not really, because in one method we want children and from other we don't. I think DTO is the only way out here.

Comment: Well, I did not see that part in your question. In that case, that it pretty clear that you need a DTO/Web layer (where you decide what the Browser gets).

Comment: As we progress forward we may be adding DTOs, but for now we are going with Alan Hay's solution.

Comment: Tried adding @JsonIgnore, but no success. Also will this impact when we want to get data  one to many , explicitly ? or vice versa when we are trying to insert into DB i.e using JSON as input & then converting to POJO & inserting the data to DB