# JPA Optimizing using custom queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, jackson

I am using JPA/Hibernate as ORM and now want to optimize my queries to only load necessary data for a specific endpoint. What's the best way to only load a subset of attributes of a specific class and then convert it to JSON? For the Endpoints I use Spring MVC and Jackson JSON Mapper.

Approaches I figured out, which I haven't tested yet.

1. Create POJO objects which only include the necessary attributes and
   map the Query fields with the attributes using
   `@SqlResultSetMapping`.

   This approach requires adding a lot of additional classes, but other
   than that it seem good.
2. Ignore the overhead in the database queries and limit my
   response data with JSONViews.

   This can get messy real fast, putting together the different
   JSONViews seems tedious. For most queries the overhead is definitely
   insignificant but I am curious how to map larger more complex
   queries.
3. Use Java.sql.PreparedStatements and map the ResultSet manually.
   Additionally use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) to only use non null
   values. For now this seems like the best solution to me, but it ignores
   JPA entirely and I am not sure if that should be my go to solution.
   I know I lose every advantage of an ORM, but it seems that every
   other solution needs similar or more complex work.
4. ???

The last couple of month I predominantly developed in JavaScript/Node and I liked that I could exactly generate the objects I needed for the response. Is there a recommended way of doing such things, to me this seems like a common use case.

thanks

Comment: As the Hibernate docs note, it is rarely worthwhile optimizing column reads: (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html section19.1.7). So you're as well loading them all and customizing the view by using the appraoches outlined here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28940610/1356423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always used POJO object for these needs before, but sometime it's more suitable to use 'select new' construction than result mapping.

```
select new com.example.MyClass(id, ...) From MyObject
```

Maybe you can consider that.

Comment: I didn't know this existed, works great. Sure if I want to do more with the object I will create a POJO, but most of my endpoints directly return the object. I am going to let the question open for a day or so, if someone wants to add anything, but I will except your answer in the next days.

Comment: And yes, if you  just want to limit amount of attributes you can create another constructor for your mapped object and use this 'select new' approach without creating additional POJO