# Spring JPA Repository ignoring FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have my entity classes with `OneToMany` mappings defined and Spring JPA repository interfaces created by extending `JpaRepository` interface of spring.

I have set fetch as `FetchType.LAZY` explicitly on the associations in `OneToMany` annotation.

The problem I'm facing is that when I get a particular record using the repository, Spring is fetching the associated entity objects which are defined using `OneToMany` annotation and their subsequent associated entity objects and so on ignoring their fetch type.I am receiving huge amount of data to the web page when use it in a Spring REST Controller. Few times, it is also resulting in a StackOverflow exception when it encounters circular bindings.

I came across the following post on stackoverflow.com but the answer didn't seem to be relevant to the current situation..

[Spring JPA loads all associated properties despite marking them as FetchType.LAZY in entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631888/spring-jpa-loads-all-associated-properties-despite-marking-them-as-fetchtype-laz)

> Update

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2700585394392789902L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate = new Date();

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate = new Date();

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User lastModifiedBy;

    @javax.persistence.Version
    private long version;

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public User getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(User lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "currencies")
public class Currency extends AbstractMasterEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Currency [code=" + code + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring DATA isn't ignoring the fact it is lazy, bt Spring Data REST exports the whole entity also lazy collections, which lead to getting the collection. Putting lazy on them doesn't influence that.

Comment: You need to use @JsonIgnore annotation to avoid data being pulled as JSON.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you. I suspected that it could be the issue.

Comment: @WeareBorg We are setting sending the json object back from the webpage to the server again to update data. When we are using JsonIgnore, the data sent back won't contain data related to the ignored fields and is being nullified when we persist the object to database using Spring JPA. Hope its clear..

Comment: Both Spring and Spring data provide mechanisms for tailoring the JSON representation of your domain model across different use cases. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28940610/1356423

Comment: Ofcourse dont ignore the fields which you might want to update. You can always update only specific fields. You are having problem with associations, I was telling you to add @JsonIgnore to associations and its getters, not actual variables of the class.

Comment: @WeareBorg I have a field 'createdBy' in my entity, I added JsonIgnore to its setter only. Yet when I update the row, createdBy becomes null in the database..

Comment: To its getters, not setters. Please post your DAO or db method for update, you can always merge fields so fields are not nullified, I do that all the time.

Comment: I've edited the question with a sample entity. We just created a Repository interface on top of this and are using its save method..

Comment: That's one of the reasons to use DTO's (data transfer object) when it comes to client-server communication. Read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application). You can map fields that you wan't to send and omit fields which you don't wan't to (like this lazily fetched collections).

Comment: Even when using DTOs for JSON responses the entity is still circularly populated in my case. And the @JsonIgnore annotation is not to be used on my entity class.