# Avoiding loading LAZY collection in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following relationship:

```
@Entity class Shop {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch = LAZY)
private List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity class Employee {
@ManyToOne
private Shop shop;
}
```

I've declared Spring Data repository like this:

```
public interface ShopRepository extends JpaRepository<Shop, Long> {}
```

Calling `ShopRepository#findOne(id)` method forces fetching of the `List<Employee> employees` which is `LAZY` relationship.

I have service which uses Shop repository:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ShopService {

private final ShopRepository shopRepository;

@Autowired
public ShopService(ShopRepository shopRepository) {
    this.shopRepository = shopRepository;
}
public Shop find(Long id) {
    return shopRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

}
The service method is called within another controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/schedule/{shopId:[0-9]+}/{date:\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Schedule getSchedule(@PathVariable Long shopId,
                            @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate date) {
    Schedule schedule = scheduleService.findSchedule(shopId, date);
    if(schedule != null)
        return schedule;
    else {
        Shop shop = shopService.find(shopId);
        Schedule empty = new Schedule(shop, date);
        return empty;
    }
}
```

**How to get rid of fetching `employees` relationship?**

Comment: I cannot see how that would be the case unless something in your code was explicitly triggering the load. Show all the code in the method calling the repo.

Comment: @alanhay, I've added the code involved in calling the repo's method.

Comment: Are you using Spring Data Rest. Is your controller a `@RepositoryRestController`? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910996/spring-jpa-repository-ignoring-fetchtype-lazy

Comment: @alan, thank you for help. Your link was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.

Actually I used @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackRefernce on my entity to prevent cycling while marshaling to JSON. It causes fetching LAZY loading data.
To avoid this you should add `Hibernate4Module` to `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

More info at this post: [Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects)