# How to apply projection Spring Data?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In my project I use Spring Data. I use Hibernate and JPA to map MySQL DB. I have a table call Customer map to the Customer class.

```
 @Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String code ;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone1;
    //getter and setter. 
}
```

I want to get **code** and **name** all customers in the database. I do I get the list of customer code and name ?

Expected JSON

[{
   "code":"001",
   "name":"cus1"

},
{
   "code":"002",
   "name":"cus2"

},
{
   "code":"003",
   "name":"cus3"

}]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve? do you want to get list of all customers from database?

use List<T> findAll(); method from JpaRepository, you will get a list of all customers

Comment: Yes. I want to get all Customers, but only code and name attributes(columns).

Comment: you can't if you return a `Customer` object ... you need for example some DTO class, which contains only code and name property, and then make a custom query to retrieve only those values ...

Comment: Could you point me a example ?

Comment: See my answer here for possible solutions in both Spring and Spring Data and without requiring overhead of creating Dtos and associated mappers :http://stackoverflow.com/a/28940610/1356423

Comment: You need to remember about different layers in your app  (data/services/presentation) app.
JPA and entities are data/domain, if you want to show JSON with name and code, you need service layer (@service stereotype) that returns DTO's with only that two fields. you don't want to send Entities outside a @Transaction scope (outside service layer).

Comment: Can we use projection for get only required values for  the DB?